# Chronometer Crashes on Reset from setOnChronometerTickListener()

Tags: java, android, chronometer

I'm trying to reset the the chronometer using `setOnChronometerTickListener()` when the chronometer reaches a certain time (in this case 5s). However it crashes when I run it on my phone. I'm using the solution to [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5345994/6232777) to reset the chronometer.

I've tried resetting the chronometer to different values but it still crashes at `chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());`

This is how I'm implementing it:

```java
chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
              if(chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("00:05")) {
                        // Reset Chronometer
                        chronometer.stop();
                        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());


              }
      }
});
```

This is the error message I get from Logcat:

```sh
2019-05-02 14:47:39.469 13143-13143/com.example.pomodoro_2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pomodoro_2, PID: 13143
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at android.widget.Chronometer.updateRunning(Chronometer.java:321)
        at android.widget.Chronometer.stop(Chronometer.java:252)
        at com.example.pomodoro_2.MainActivity$3.onChronometerTick(MainActivity.java:88)
        at android.widget.Chronometer.dispatchChronometerTick(Chronometer.java:347)
        at android.widget.Chronometer.setBase(Chronometer.java:176)
```

I assume from this error message that I'm overflowing the stack, but I can't figure out why and have not seen a similar error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: start and stop chronometer inside handler with postDelay and check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put a log inside your if condition, you see that log in logcat after 00:05.
i prevent it by removing listener from chronometer.

```
chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
              if(chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("00:05")) {
                        // Reset Chronometer
                        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(null);
                        chronometer.stop();
                        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());


              }
      }
});
```

but if you need this listener, you can implements your fragment from *Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener* and implement OnChronometerTickListener such as below:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener {

    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button start;
    Chronometer chronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chron);
        start = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chronometer.start();
            }
        });
        chronometer.start();
        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        if (chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("00:05")) {
            // Reset Chronometer
            chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(null);
            chronometer.stop();
            Log.d(TAG, "onChronometerTick: stop");

            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(this);


        }

    }
}
```